# Vue js. Как передать данные из js дочернего компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js, listener

У меня есть два файла

1: Vue компонент

```
<template>
<details class="microservices">
    <summary><h1>Дата</h1></summary>
    <div class="manifest">
        <div>
            Установите дату
            <div>{{curentTimer}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</details>
</template>
<script>
import obj from './methods/index.js' // подключаемый файл
setInterval(obj[1].getTime(this), 1000)
export default {
  props: ['timer'],
  name: 'date',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    curentTimer () {
      // вычисляемое свойство для таймера
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // set
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import '../../../../assets/model/index';
</style>
```

2: Второй файл подключается к компоненте.

```
let obj = [{
   getDate () {
   return '[(Init)]'
  }
},
  {
    getTime (state) {
     console.log('method[(index)obj]', state)
     // state.commit('setTimer', '!!!!!!!!!')
   }
}]
export default obj
```

В 1 файле стоит

```
setInterval(obj[1].getTime(this), 1000)
```

Значение обновляется каждую секунду.

Мне надо реактивно обновлять значение в 1 файле(vue component)
Как оптимально передать данные из дочернего (2 файла) ?

Это делается с помощью $emit $on

// Генерируем событие, возможно с передаваемыми данными

```
this.$emit('название' [, данные]);
```

// Слушаем событие

```
this.$on('название', function(данные) {...});
```

Примеры в интернете показывают как это сделать через template.

Я хочу что бы у меня значение обновлялось в свойстве компонента и если мне потребуется выводить его в template.

Как такое правильно записать ?
Через mutations значение в vuex обновляется.
И по идее this.$store.getters.time в computed:{} должно реактивно изменяться в компоненте но не изменяется.

Answer (score 0):

Для подключения функций из внешнего файла обычно используются [mixin](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) (примеси).

`mixin` очень похожа по структуре на структуру компонента, имеет свойства `data`, `methods`, и прочие. При этом, эти свойства дополняют сам компонент, а подключить эту `mixin` можно в разных компонентах.

Если Вам необходимо использовать `vuex`, то обратите внимание, что для получения к нему доступа необходимо использовать свойство `$store` в самом компоненте, а не до его объявления.

Неправильно

```
import obj from './methods/index.js' // подключаемый файл
setInterval(obj[1].getTime(this), 1000) 
export default {
```

Правильно

```
export default {
  created() {
    window.setInterval(obj[1].getTime(this.$store), 1000) 
  }
```

В примере используется хук [created](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created). Этот хук вызывается при создании компонента.

Насчет реактивности мутаций все верно.

Неудобно, что Вы не привели выполняемый код. Возможно, есть еще какие - нибудь неясности в коде.